# Background gradient position

Tags: html, css

I have a "right" gradient that I'm trying to position it so that it stops 20px from the bottom of my div. Meaning, the gradient flows from left to right but the bottom 20 pixels of my div I would like it to be white.

I've tried the positioning code below and it has worked without the image but I can't get it to work with the image.

If you look at the image, you can see what I'm trying to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
height: 200px;


background-image: url("http://www.vovoaki.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vovoakiheader1.jpg"), -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,white,white,white) no-repeat 0px -20px;
background-image: url("http://www.vovoaki.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vovoakiheader1.jpg"), -o-linear-gradient(right,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,white,white,white)  no-repeat 0px -20px;
background-image: url("http://www.vovoaki.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vovoakiheader1.jpg"), -moz-linear-gradient(right,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,white,white,white) no-repeat 0px -20px;
background-image: url("http://www.vovoaki.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vovoakiheader.png"), linear-gradient(to right,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,white,white,white) no-repeat 0px -20px;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: [This online tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) is really helpful for generating gradients

Comment: and what's your HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it would work but neither the image or the gradient have any transparency so in the example they will cover each other up in every which order you place them :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPKKMO?editors=010

```
div {
height: 200px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,white,white,white) top left / 100% calc(100% - 20px), url(http://www.vovoaki.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vovoakiheader.png) top left / 100% 100%;
background: linear-gradient(to right,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,#24a2b5,white,white,white) top left / 100% calc(100% - 20px), url(http://www.vovoaki.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/vovoakiheader.png) top left / 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

I've reversed the placement here otherwise the gradient wouldn't be visible at all. Just focused on the it's height so the other dimensions may be off from what would be intended.

Comment: The reason I had the image on top of the gradient was to make it look responsive. In wider screens it would look like the the sides of the image (blue and white) would "stretch" when in fact it's just the background gradient showing up. Thank you though, this helps me out a great deal. I know how to make it work now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that sounds like a nice effect. Stacking backgrounds can be tricky when it comes to the markup (took me a bit to get this one right as well) but it's certainly a great feature.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a div around that, and set the CSS to

```
padding-bottom:20px;
```

So you have

```
<div class="paddingBTM"><div class="gradient"></div></div>
```